# rails custom action in nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route that looks as so:

```
  resources :contacts do
    resources :leads do
      get :process, on: :member
    end
  end
```

It generates the following helper:

```
process_contact_lead_path   GET /contacts/:contact_id/leads/:id/process(.:format)   leads#process
```

Now when I try to use it like so:

```
link_to "Process", process_contact_lead_path(@contact, @lead)
```

The following happens:

```
Started GET "/contacts/2/leads/2/process" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-10 13:57:05 -0500

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):
```

It is expecting my controller action to look like this:

```
  def process(arg)
    puts arg # => process
  end
```

So the Rails controller is expecting an argument which is the string "process". Obviously I am doing something wrong. Process is the action to be called and not an argument to pass to the controller action.

How can I address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by a method name conflict. [process](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4d5e6607899832bde1365bdd4f7617a24bca4561/actionview/lib/action_view/rendering.rb#L28) is an internal method of `Rendering`. The simplest thing to do is to just rename the action in routes or route it to a different action.

```
resources :contacts do
  resources :leads do
    get :process, on: :member, to: "leads#process_action"
  end
end
```